# How to throw an error message when same language is selected using autocomplete in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Hai i have a language field, if i click on add button duplicate language fields are generated. Here if i select one language and if i select the same language again it is taking.
So, how do i avoid multiple entry of same language.

HTML:

```
        <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left m-b10 m-t10">
          <label class="col-sm-5 pull-left col-form-label g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-700 text-sm-left no-padd">Language</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7 pull-left no-padd">
            <input type='text' (keyup)="searchDropDown(176, src7.value ,i)" #src7 formControlName="Language" minlength="3" placeholder="Language"
            />
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            <div *ngIf="patientDropdown && patientDropdown?.language && IsHidden && contactIndex == i" class="emr-dropdown">
              <ul *ngFor="let languageType of patientDropdown?.language" (click)="getValue(languageType, i)" class="p-l10 m-b0 brd-b">
                <li>
                  {{languageType.Description}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

TS:

```
public initializeAllDropDown(data) {
    this.patientDropdown = <PatientDropDown>{
      language: data.filter(r => r.CategoryId == '176'),
    }
  }

  public searchDropDown(Id, desc, index) {
    let params = { Id, desc: desc }
    this.emrService.getDropDown(params)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.IsHidden = true;
        this.initializeAllDropDown(res.Body.Data)
      })
  }

  public getValue(item, cntrl) {
    this.IsHidden = false;
    if (item.CategoryId == 176) {
      this.Communicationx.at(cntrl).get('Language').setValue(item.Description)
    }
  }
```

**Console of Item:**

```
(43) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {StatusId: 16269, CategoryId: 176, Code: "ar", Description: "Arabic", Status: 2, …}
1: {StatusId: 16270, CategoryId: 176, Code: "bn", Description: "Bengali", Status: 2, …}

length: 43
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Here i am differentiating different fields of dropdowns through the categoryID so based on that dropdowns are assigned to particular fields.

Updated:

```
public getValue(item, cntrl) {
    console.log(item);
    this.IsHidden = false;
    if (item.CategoryId == 176) {
      this.selectedLanguage.push(item)
      this.Communicationx.at(cntrl).get('Language').setValue(item.Description)
    }
    let existedLanguage = this.selectedLanguage.filter(
      lang => lang.Description == item.Description
    )[0];
    if (!existedLanguage) {
      if (item.CategoryId == 176) {
        this.selectedLanguage.push(item)
        this.Communicationx.at(cntrl).get('Language').setValue(item.Description)
      }
    } else {
      alert('you already selected this language')
    }
  }
```

Comment: you're using bootstrap, simply add a `disabled` css class to an added item

Comment: can you console `item` and also what is `item.CategoryId == 176` condition

Comment: jus keep 2 lines of console and remove others

Comment: @Sravan updated as u said

Comment: @Sravan is that updated correct? is that what i wanted to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take an `array` and store the `sleected values`, and check in that `array` when you select next time.

In your `component`:

`public selectedLanguages = [];`

Now, `push` into `array` using,

`this.selectedLanguages.push(item)`

```
public getValue(item, cntrl) {
    this.IsHidden = false;
    if (item.CategoryId == 176) {
      this.selectedLanguages.push(item)
      this.Communicationx.at(cntrl).get('Language').setValue(item.Description)
    }
 }
```

Then, you can keep a condition check for language and display an error message using Toastr or an alert:

```
public getValue(item, cntrl) {
    console.log(item, 'aaaaaaaaaa');
    this.IsHidden = false;
    let existedLanguage = this.selectedLanguage.filter(
      lang => lang.Description == item.Description
    )[0];
    console.log(existedLanguage, 'bbbbbbbbb')
    if (!existedLanguage) {
      if (item.CategoryId == 176) {
        this.selectedLanguage.push(item)
        this.Communicationx.at(cntrl).get('Language').setValue(item.Description)
      }
    } else {
      alert('you already selected this language')
    }
  }
```

Comment: I updated my answewr and added console, pls add that code and send console when firstime selecting dropdown

Answer (score -1):

You can use a set:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Or you can add a flag to your language store and hide li if it is set.